# How can I use the official composer image within docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: php7.1-apache-stretch
        container_name: php-app
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8080:80
    composer:
        image: composer:1.8
        container_name: composer-app
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
```

However when I run `docker-compose up` the only running container is the `php-app`. How can I run the composer within the docker-compose file and communicate with my app container?

Comment: The "composer" image is not meant to be used in that way. Please have a look at the official page "https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/" for how to use it. The idea is to map a volume with your code inside the container and then run the "install" command.

Comment: Ah I see.. so you can use this in cases like running the commands if you haven't installed the composer locally like creating a new laravel project etc. But how you can map it with the container app? can you give me an example, so I can approve your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you use the Composer image in a multistage build to avoid having to install it and all its dependencies on the host.

To do that create a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM composer:1.8 AS composer

FROM php:7.1-apache-stretch

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# Place here your command that uses Composer
RUN composer install
```

Note: You need to review the RUN command since I am not a PHP developer .... ;)

Now the docker-compose.yml looks something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: php-app:1.0
    container_name: "php-app"
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
```

You don't need the volume anymore since the files are copied inside the image at build time.

Build the image and run the service:

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: So, if I set my dockerfile like this then I should be also able to run `docker run --rm --interactive --tty composer create-project laravel/laravel` ?

Comment: I would say yes. Again I am not familiar with php but if those are the commands you normally pass to "composer" then it will work.